# Can an older version of IE run in a newer document mode? (e.g. IE7 rendering in Document Mode IE9)

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I'm building a webpage and I'm testing it using the IE developer tools to see how it might look in older versions of IE.

If I'm testing in Browser Mode: IE7, do I HAVE to set the Document Mode to IE7 as well?  I ask becuase if I keep the Document Mode as IE9 standards, my page displays fine. But if I change it to Document Mode: IE7. It's a mess.

**I want to know if IE7 (original browser) can use the IE9 Document Mode.**  This might be obvious to some people, but then why would Microsoft allow you to view a page in IE7 browser mode with an IE9 Document Mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to help sort out some of those incompatibilites, but you cannot make IE7 behave like IE9, or IE8 for that matter, in terms of how it renders.

Browsers need to be pretty resilient to changes in doc types, and Microsoft have made sure that IE is pretty tolerant to all sorts of bad html.  I'm not quite sure what you mean in the last sentence, but allowing you to view a page in IE7 is just a way of providing some form of backward compatibility from MS.  Have a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/03/24/ie9-s-document-modes-and-javascript.aspx).

Comment: Thanks.  My last sentance refers to the fact that in IE9, if you open the developer tools panel, you can change your Browser Mode to IE7, and then set your Document Mode to IE9.  To me, this tells me that IE7 can display using an IE9 Document Mode because otherwise, why would they have 2 independent drop down settings?  Why would they allow you to view a document using the IE7 Browser Mode and at the same time using an IE9 Document Mode?